# Including header for Http2 including css, js and files in php for server push

Tags: php, http-headers, assets, http2, server-push

After successfully including the http2 in apache2. I was facing the problem for the server push. I have 4-5 css ,4-5 js and 100 images in the site. So how would i work with multiple assets?

```
    <link href="source" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="source"></script>
    <img src="source">
   header('Link: </asset/to/push.js>; rel=preload; as=script')
```

so i have to header for each and every assets if i have 100 assets there will be 100 header or so

Comment: Yup. You have to do them 1 by 1.

Comment: Also you need to use the header function before sending out real content

Comment: @KoalaYeung cant it be done in htaccess or something tell the code that if .css extension come make it as server push

Comment: The server push header should be added to pages that needs the asset. For example if your `login.php` needs `css/style.css`, it is the `login.php` file should provide the server push header.

Comment: Your Apache wouldn't know what asset(s) you'd need for a certain HTML page.

Comment: Probably we can use regex in htaccess to match the files or extension

Comment: It is not the loading of css that push the css. It is the loading of an HTML / PHP that should identify the css or images that should be push along. How do you propose to do that with regex?

Comment: files starting with .css, .js, .jpg, .png should be pushed for our current scenario thats how :)

Comment: How do you trigger the push header? As I explained over and over again, You cannot trigger it from .css, .js, .jpg or .png file load.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative solution to adding the `Link` headers and have Apache parse them and push the associated resources, is to naturally correlate secondary resources such as `js`, `css` and image files to the primary resource.

This is the approach that we have taken in Jetty (disclaimer, I am the implementor of that solution).

We use this solution to serve our own Website, based on WordPress, over HTTP/2 with HTTP/2 Push.

The approach is presented here: [slides](https://webtide.com/http2-push-demo/), [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QpLtBftqM04).

The basic idea is that when a browser received an HTML page, it immediately parses it and perform the requests needed to download secondary resources such as `js` and `css` files.
The server, in this case Jetty, can correlate the primary resource (the `html`) with the secondary resources.

The next time a request for the same `html` page arrives, Jetty already knows what are the secondary resources needed, and can push them.
There is no need for `Link` headers, as Jetty "learns" what are the resources needed by a page from the request patterns that the browser performs.

This approach can be fine tuned on basis to basis, but works fine out of the box and provides dramatic performance improvements, see [here for the live demo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QpLtBftqM04&t=2665) in the video linked above.

I recommend to read/watch the whole slides/video for a larger context about HTTP/2 and HTTP/2 Push, but the point is that the combination Jetty + PHP with HTTP/2 is a powerful solution for HTTP/2 Push and requires no changes to PHP pages - which is perfect when using PHP frameworks such as WordPress or Drupal, and to avoid adding 100+ `Link` headers to your PHP pages.

Comment: so we cannot push the images from other server for e.g pushing images from http://google.com/logo.png in my server

Comment: You can push images from your own server, but not from other servers.

Comment: are there any bad effects of http2 on server as we upgraded the http1 to http2 with implementation of server we were not able to see the drastic change.

Comment: If you don't see any difference, then you probably have not configured HTTP/2 Push correctly, or you are using a server with a faulty implementation, or your case is very peculiar (although it looks like a case where HTTP/2 should work well).

Comment: faulty implementation? i am using with nginx and apache ..isnt the http2 is launched officially with full tested for these two?

Comment: Even the best software has problems. Just search here in SO for other HTTP/2 questions, and you'll see that implementations are far from perfect. Not only normal bugs, but also optimizations that can only be made with time and experience - and HTTP/2 is a relatively new protocol.

Answer (score 0):

Just push whats really needed early, otherwise you might end up with no performance benefit at all.

Thats how i add an Icon-Font:

```
header("link: </fonts/icons.woff2?v=".$version.">; rel=preload; as=font; type=\"font/woff2\" nopush", false);
```

Do not forget to set the replace=false when using multiple link-headers.